# How do you create attach a warning to a function in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, warnings, compiler-warnings

I'm writing an SDK for iOS and would like to warn developers when using a function that it should be for debug only, not for their release builds. I want the function to have a warning sign attached to it whenever it is used by the developers to remind them that they should not release the app with this function.

I know I could add the deprecated attribute to the function, but that would not be accurate. The method is not deprecated, it is a method for QA only and should not be in the wild for end users.

Comment: What language? Objective-C or Swift?

Comment: I'm using Objective-C

Answer (score 0):

Just write the following where your warning should be.

```
#warning <insert whatever your warning text should be>
```

Answer (score 0):

Surround your method with conditional compile statements:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
- (void) myDebuggingMethod {
// stuff goes here
}
#endif
```

That way if they use it for a release build (where DEBUG is not defined), it will generate an error and not allow them to compile at all.

You can also use this to surround your calls to this method so that the code will always build.